# Percentage of the normal area - How to find the area under the normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, self-learning

First this is not my homework is an example for learn and solve this little problem.

[image]

(Reference online pdf [here](http://www.lamission.edu/math/docs/m227faculty/sample_homework/wong/227_ch6-hw-soln.pdf).)

I have problems only with this section in exercise text:

> The middle $60\%$ means that $30\%$ of the area will be on either side of the mean. The corresponding $z$ score is found using $\rm{area} = 0.20$. The $z$ scores are $\pm 0.84$.

How did they find the area is $0.2$ they skipped this part?

Comment: Hint: How big is the not shaded area?

Comment: oh my god what a brain bug in that moment thk u. why you all users that can comment here not post the hint or answer for be accepted?

Comment: At your service ... Don't worry about brain bugs, we all suffer from time to time from them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have problems only with this section in exercise text:

> The middle $60\%$ means that $30\%$ of the area will be on either side of the mean. The corresponding $z$ score is found using $\rm{area} = 0.20$. The $z$ scores are $\pm 0.84$.

**There is an evident typo**....it is not 30% but 40% (total) that is on both tails, 20% on the left one and 20% on the right one. Obviously $20\%=0.2$

thus you will claculate the two quantiles corresponding to

$$P(Z<z)=0.2$$

that is

$$\Phi^{-1}(0.2)=-0.84$$

and

$$P(Z>z)=0.2$$

that is

$$\Phi^{-1}(0.8)=0.84$$

Comment: oh looks like my brain bug was that typo error... be careful with pdf samples and solutions. they are taking too many shorcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How big is the not shaded area?